# Removing all English and other punctuation form the text file in Jupyter

Tags: python, text, nlp, jupyter

I have a text file I wanted to work on some NLP task. But I am processing for Local language. That file contains lots of English words and Punctuation marks. I wanted to get rid of all the Latin and other punctuation from that text file. How this is possible using Jupyter notebook
TIA

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, you can accomplish this with just Python

```
text = "Hello, World!!"
# put everything you wish to filter out in this list
filterList = [',', '!']

filteredList = filter(lambda c: c not in filterList, text)
print(''.join(filteredList))
```

Will give `Hello World`

Comment: what if that is a text file? not simply text?

Comment: If its a file you need to read in the file so it becomes text, filter it, then write the result back to a file. Presumably you need to load the file into memory anyways to train your model